# Monitoring changes in web page through mobile app

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, mobile

I am trying to develop a mobile app that monitors a web page(remote and not administered by me), such that whenever the content(body tag) of that page changes, my app come to know of that change and notifies the user.

I want to develop this mobile app using phonegap, jquery/javascript but can't use any server side language. After a lot of research, i thought of using YQL(Yahoo query language). It takes the url of the web page and returns its html in json format. I then stringify the json and calculate its unique hashcode using javascript and save the hashcode. I keep repeating these steps after every 5 minutes and keep comparing the hashcodes. If there is any change in hashcode, i get to know that the content of the web page is changed.

Although it is working good, but I was wondering if there is any alternative way of doing it because it seems very inefficient to grab entire page to a mobile and then store its hashcode? Any way which is more efficient?

Thanks

Comment: do it on a server using html parser otherwise due to cross domain restrictions you don't have much choice with javascript than what you are doing

Comment: can't use server side script because I am developing a mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the webpage but in practice you can make a `HEAD` request instead of a `GET` request then check the `Last-Modified` header if present. Though, then you'd have to make a normal `GET` request to get the body contents if the `Last-Modified` date has changed

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for something like this. I will try and let you know if it works for me.